# MySQL order by after grouping works unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, group-by

how is it that a query like this works in MySQL (on 5.6 right now):

```
SELECT node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
FROM nested_category AS node,
        nested_category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
GROUP BY node.name
ORDER BY node.lft;
```

I am very confused, I am used to SQL Server, where it would complain that the node.lft is not in the list of selected columns, but here in MySQL it works great,

I appreciate your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct to be confused.  MySQL allows this behavior -- and not only in the `order by`, but also in the `having` and `select` clauses as well.

Basically, MySQL uses a value from an *indeterminate* matching row.  In general, this is a (mis)feature in the language and leads to unintentional errors -- in most cases.

It is reasonable when the values of `node.lft` are the same on all rows in a group.  In that case, though, using something like `MIN(node.lft)` incurs very little additional overhead.

Some notes about this behavior:

- MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html) -- through version 5.6 -- warns specifically about this feature.
- ANSI supports a very similar feature.  Basically, if the columns being referenced are functionally dependent (i.e. uniquely determined by) the columns in the `group by`, then the columns are allowed with no aggregation functions.
- MySQL documentation in version 5.7 drops the full explanation of the feature, probably because the database is moving toward the ANSI standard in this area.